# Heat equation and smoothness effect

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

Consider the homogeneous heat system with Dirichlet B.C

\begin{array}{c}
u_{t}-u_{xx}=0 \\ 
u(0,t)=u(\pi ,t)=0 \\ 
u(x,0)=f(x).%
\end{array}
It is well known that the solution of the system above is given by

$$u(t,x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}A_{n}e^{-n^{2}t}\sin (nx)$$,

Also, it is well known that $u\in C^{\infty }((0,T]\times (0,\pi ))$ for any 
$f\in L^{2}(0,\pi ).$ (Smoothness effect).

My question is : What if there exists some function $f\in X$ such that $%
A_{n}\sim e^{n^{2}},$ where $X$ is some Hilbert or Banach space, the
solution will not exist,

Is there any initial condition and some $X$ which satisfy that ?

Thanks.